# "Das sind" instead of "die sind"?

Tags: pronoun, subject

I have seen sentences like these that really confuses me such as:

> "Das sind unsere."
>   "Das sind Katzen."

As far my as understanding allows the definite articles (der, die, das, die) can also be used as demonstrative pronouns this/that. If that's the case here why does the pronoun NOT agree with the subject? Doesn't "das" represent singular neuter while "unsere" and "katzen" are in plural?

Comment: Ich würde diese Frage vorläufig nicht schließen, da man das Demonstrativpronomen in diesem Fall höchstens mit Es/Sie in einen Topf wirft, wenn man die Antwort schon kennt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated above "das" is the common demonstrative pronoun - **independent of gender and number**. You can thus say

> Das sind meine Brüder.

And it would  be the generic choice. But "der/die/das" is a demonstrative pronoun as well. **So what you are seeing is technically not the definite article, but a pronoun that is identical to it!** As a demonstrative pronoun alone "der/die/das" has 10 sub uses in my dictionary.

> But I believe what you are interested in here is the **contrasting** use of the demonstrative "der".

I try to make an example where both "das" and "der" are used idiomatically, the first neutrally and the second for contrast:

```
Wer ist der Mann mit der Sonnenbrille?
Das ist mein Freund!
Und was ist mit Martin?
Der hat mich verlassen!
```

Translation:

```
Who is the man with the sun glasses?
That's my boyfriend!
And what about Martin?
He (contrasting) has left me!
```

More examples of "der/die/das" as a contrasting demonstrative pronoun include:

```
Welcher ist dein Vater? / Which one is your father?
Der mit der Glatze...  / The one with the bald head.
```

Answer (score 2):

The word "*das*" is normally used as "generic" demonstrative pronoun.

When the word does not refer to another word already mentioned you use "*das*":

> **These** are our cats.

You use the word "*das*".

Only when the pronoun refers to another word already mentioned you can use "*der*" or "*die*":

> Q: Wessen **Schlüsselbund** ist **das**?
>
> A 1: **Der** ist mein Schlüsselbund.
>
> A 2: **Das** ist mein Schlüsselbund.
>
> A 3: **Der** gehört mir.

In the question the demonstrative pronoun does not refer to another word. So the word "*das*" is used.

In the answers (1) and (3) the pronoun refers to the word "*Schlüsselbund*" (in the question) so the word "*der*" is used.

In the answer (2) the pronoun "*das*" does not refer to the word "*Schlüsselbund*" already said.

Most Germans would use answers (2) and (3) but they would not use answer (1) for some reason I don't know.

Comment: Ich halte "Der ist mein Schlüsselbund" für einen Satz, den ein in Deutschland und Österreich sprachsozialisierter Mensch nicht sagen würde. Ein solcher Mensch würde sagen **"Das** ist mein Schlüsselbund". (Es sei denn es gäbe Sprachinseln vielleicht im tiefen Norden irgendwo, wo man so spricht; aber auch das halte ich für unwahrscheinlich.)

Comment: "Der ist mein Schlüsselbund" klingt für mich nicht idiomatisch! Schon gar nicht im Norden!

Comment: Tja... da wäre es nun wohl an Martin Rosenau, zu erhellen, wo er eine solche Formulierung im Alltag realiter trifft. - Ich kann mir allerdings folgenden Dialog vorstellen: A: "Kuck mal die fünf Schlüsselbünde da auf dem Tisch, welcher davon ist deiner?" - B: "Der da ist meiner."

Comment: *Wem gehört der Schlüssebund hier?* - *Der ist meiner!* habe ich sowohl in Franken als auch in Hessen gehört, und ich bin mir nahezu sicher, dass das auch in anderen Regionen verbreitet ist.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Das gibt es natürlich und es ist die kontrastierende Verwendung des Demonstrativpronomens. Aber den Satz in der Antwort (mit wiederholtem Nomen!)  habe ich noch nie gehört. Dazu bedürfte es des folgenden verrückten Dialogs mit personifizierten Gegenständen: "Wer ist Fltzi? Das ist mein Auto! Und wer ist Safey? Der ist mein Schlüsselbund!"

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Ich habe meine Antwort etwas editiert. Ich hatte auch in der "Original-Antwort" einen etwas versteckten Satz drin, der besagt hat, dass man in den meisten Fällen wohl "*das*" und nicht "*der*" sagen würde. Jetzt ist er wohl weniger versteckt.